# How to justify menu item accelerators to the different menu width?

Tags: css, javafx, menu, java-8

My `menu-button` is a bit wider:

```
.menu-button {
  -fx-pref-width: 250px;
  -fx-background-color: #72b3c9;
  -fx-padding: 5 16 5 16;
}
```

and the menu with its items (and their accelerators) is displayed as expected, like this:

[image: default]

But when I want to align the width of `menu-item` to the width of `menu-button`, like this:

```
.menu-item {
  -fx-pref-width: 250px;
  -fx-pref-height: 40px;
  -fx-padding: 5px 16px 5px 16px;
}
```

then I don't get the accelerators aligned to the right of the menu items:

[image]

**What I would want (and expect)** is that the accelerators are following the width of the menu item and that are aligned to the right edges of their respective menu items, like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

**Edit:**

A hack to increase the left-label padding could be used, thus forcing the accelerators more to the right:

```
.menu-item .label {
  -fx-padding: 0 120px 0 0;
}
```

But, that is a hard-coded platform-dependent approach that needs to be adjusted each time a menu item label text or an accelerator is changed.

Comment: A question, how do you display two (texts) items on the same line of an `menu-item`?

Comment: @BoHalim, those are not two separate items, but a menu item and its accelerator. The accelerator is added programmatically with `menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination(keyCombination));`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I managed to achieve, like that with the default color it will not appear but if you put two differents color (for `Label` and `Background`) it will be ugly for now it is the only thing That I realized. I know something is missing but I can't figure out what :

```
 .menu-button {

  -fx-pref-width: 250px;
  -fx-background-color: #72b3c9;

 }

 .menu-item {

   -fx-pref-width: 250px;

 }

 .menu-item > .label{

  -fx-pref-width: 200px;

 }
```

[image: Overview]

Try to perfect it, on my side I will try to find a better solution, good luck !

Comment: I've tried that approach, but it forces the accelerators to be left-aligned instead of right. Try setting the second accelerator with a longer key combination e.g. "Ctrl+Shift+S" and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its already a very old question and probably you have found some solution. But I am giving my answer here so that others can find it useful.

Don't set any width for `.menu-item` or it's child `.menu-item > .label`. Set the padding only in `.accelerator-text` instead as follows:

```
.menu-item > .accelerator-text {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

Customize the left padding to adjust your menu item's width.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it is not flexible enough. It does allow right-aligned accelerator texts, but as their containers are not right-aligned to the menu, any change to the accelerator or menu item text disrupts the "hardcoded" alignment.
Just try setting the second accelerator with a longer key combination e.g. "Ctrl+Shift+S" and you'll see the problem.